# Finding C for which f(x) is a density function

Tags: probability, density-function, integral

One of the points of the exercise states:

> Find the constant $C$ for which the following function is a density function

$$
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    C(x-x^2)       & 0 \leq x \leq 2\\
    0              & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

My first thought were to put $$\int_0^2 f(x) = 1$$ which leads to:
$$C \int_0^2 x-x^2 dx = 1 \Rightarrow C = - \frac{3}{2}$$
BUT I've also noticed that the function has 2 roots, one in $0$ and one in $1$ so this solution would have the region from 0 to 1 having negative values.
I cannot find a way to get one $C$ which satisfies both the condition of non negativity and the integral over the region $= 1$, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such constant. Density values should always be non-negative. In $[0,1]$, $x-x^2$ is non-negative so $C\geq0$. And, in $[1,2]$, $x-x^2$ is *nonpositive* so $C\leq0$. The intersection is $C=0$, but then the integral cannot be $1$.

Comment: This makes me wonder if the exercise was quoted verbatim.